# How do you enable translation for a field which was defined by a contrib module?

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n

I am trying to enable translation for a field which was defined by a different module.

The problem is this field does not list in the UI. When I checked the definition for this field in `hook_entity_field_storage_info` I can see the `setTranslatable(TRUE)` is missing. So I added the same in `hook_entity_field_storage_info_alter` . After this I can see the field listing in the UI for translation, but when I enable the checkbox and submit the value is not saved.

How can I enable translation for this field?

Comment: Could you provide some more information, what module does the field come from, what is the name of the entity, what is the name of the field etc. That would make it easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: So, the module which I'm using is https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_reviewer . 
`workbench_reviewer` is the field which I'm trying to update to enable translation.
After checking here - https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742 I tried `Updating an existing field storage definition` in `hook_update_n` .
Then I added `hook_entity_field_storage_info_alter` and `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter` to my module. After this I could see the field appearing in UI for translation. This method works for me. Just wanted to see if a better solution is out there. If not I can add this as answer.

Comment: Is the solution in the OP fully functional or not? You mention "when I enable the checkbox and submit the value is not saved.", which sounds as if this is not working. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Unfortunately the field is added by code so there is no other way to modify its definition other that implementing an hook_update_N. For fields installed using configuration files (e.g. body field for node), once the field is installed the site owns the configuration so can be easily edited and updated (if the field has no content).

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of struggle and research, here is the approach taken -

**custom_module.install file -**

```
/**
 * Enable translation for workbench_reviewer field.
 * Implements hook_update_n.
*/
function hook_update_xxxx() {
  $entity_definition_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $field_storage_definition_node = $entity_definition_update_manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('workbench_reviewer', 'node');
  $field_storage_definition_node->setTranslatable(TRUE);
  $entity_definition_update_manager->updateFieldStorageDefinition($field_storage_definition_node);

}
```

**custom_module.module file -**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_field_storage_info_alter().
 */
function hook_entity_field_storage_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  // Alter translation settings.
  if (($entity_type->id() == 'node' || $entity_type->id() == 'taxonomy_term') && !empty($fields['workbench_reviewer'])) {
    $fields['workbench_reviewer']->setTranslatable(TRUE);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter().
 */
function hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  // Alter translation settings.
  if (($entity_type->id() == 'node' || $entity_type->id() == 'taxonomy_term') && !empty($fields['workbench_reviewer'])) {
    $fields['workbench_reviewer']->setTranslatable(TRUE);
  }
}
```

Once running `drush updb` I can see the field appearing in translation UI with the **checkbox enabled**.

Comment: Could you patch the workbench reviewer module ?

Comment: Yes, in this case that would be the proper way to proceed. Drupal core's is multilingual by design so any contrib should follow that pattern. Thanks @DanielHarper for point it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can set it to “Translatable” at the “Entity” level and as such you need the following hook.

```
hook_entity_base_field_info_alter
```

It alters existing field definitions -like ones defined by other modules.
There is also

```
[hook_entity_base_field_info]
```

to provide new field definitions

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_base_field_info/8.8.x

The hook you used **[hook_entity_field_storage_info_alter]** works at the field level.

For example, if some module wanted to create Entity for new field ( called my-title) and make it Translatable  at the “Entity” level it would be like:

```
$fields[‘my-title’] = BaseFieldDefinition::create(‘string’)
   →setTranslatable(TRUE);
```

So, the the hook(described above) is changing such a “base definition of the given Entity”.

The Steps you will need in your code is:

1) Load the given Entity.

2) Set it by using [setTranslatable(TRUE)].

3) save it (similar to $node→save();).

For example, for the “Article” NodeType,  step 1 can be

```
$type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()→getStorage(‘node_type’)→
load(article’);
```

Check out the following for deeper understanding:

```
\Drupal\core\Entity\Query\QueryInterface.

 BaseFieldDefinition’s setTranslatable method
  & isTranslatable method
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/class/BaseFieldDefinition/8.8.x

The docs have it buried it

> In Drupal 8 field language is no longer exposed in the public API,
>   instead fields are attached to language-aware entity objects from
>   which they "inherit" their language

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/entity-translation-api

Comment: This already dicussed by OP on the question itself and the comments and also does not provides an actual answer or relevant facts about the question per-se. The OP is asking about if theres any other way (besides `hook_entity_field_storage_info_alter`) to enable translation for a field provided by a contrib module

Comment: Nope. The hooks are different -look closely and remove the downvote. The one I provided has _base_.

Comment: The hook I provided targets the “Entity” not the “Field”

Comment: I know they are different the point is the question make by the OP:  This method works for me. Just wanted to see if a better solution is out there. If not I can add this as answer. The answer no theres no other method regardless the fields is a base or bundle field. also the module referred by the OP uses a bundle not a base field https://git.drupalcode.org/project/workbench_reviewer/blob/8.x-2.x/workbench_reviewer.module#L52

Comment: Also your answer is incomplete, you cannot alter a field definition once installed, you need to implement an update, the OP already discovered that.